# How to implement a special character(?) as an option in a Switch of type 'char'?

Tags: java, switch-statement, special-characters

I am attempting to use a Switch statement to use as a menu interface, and I was wondering how I can include a "help" option, which is triggered by the user having input a '?' symbol.

But as the Switch is accepting type 'char', I am not sure how this is possible.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Here is my non-compiling code so far:

```
private char readChoice()
{   System.out.print("Choice (a/b/c/s/?/x): ");
    return In.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0); }

private void execute(char choice)
{   switch (choice)
    {   case 'a': routes.show(); break;
        case 'b': customers.book(routes); break;
        case 'c': customers.show(); break;
        case 's': routes.showSchedule(); break; 
        case '\?': showHelp(); break;
        case 'x': break;    }}

private String showHelp()
{   String helpText = "  A/a  Show bookings by route\n";
    helpText +=       "  B/b Book a trip\n";
    helpText +=       "  C/c Show bookings by customer\n";
    helpText +=       "  ? Show choices\n";
    helpText +=       "  X/x Exit\n";
    return helpText;    }
```

One other question, is there a more suitable way to implement the 'Exit' option, rather than just having a break after an 'x' is input?

Thank you for taking the time to read through my question.

Comment: Not related to your question, just something you should know. First of all: use `java.lang.StringBuilder` to concatenate several strings, it's more efficient than using `+=`. Second: in this example, there's no need to do concatenation, just type the whole thing as one string literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special about the question mark character within the Java language. You don't need to escape it - it's not like in a regular expression. Just use:

```
case '?': showHelp(); break;
```

See [JLS section 3.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4) for the characters you *do* need to escape (and the escape sequences available).

EDIT: As per the comments, the problem is with the `showHelp()` method, which builds a string but doesn't return it. You probably want something like:

```
private String showHelp() {
    out.println("  A/a  Show bookings by route");
    out.println("  B/b Book a trip");
    out.println("  C/c Show bookings by customer");
    out.println("  ? Show choices");
    out.println("  X/x Exit");
}
```

... for a suitable value of `out`.

(As an aside, your bracing style is odd and I for one find it pretty hard to read. There are two common bracing styles in Java - the one I showed in the above code, and the "brace on a separate line at the same indentation as the closing brace" version. For the sake of others who might read your code, it's probably worth adopting one of those common styles.)

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I did actually try that, and it compiled, although for whatever reason when I tested it, after inputting '?', the help script did not print. Can you see any obvious reason that this would be the case?

Comment: @AlexM It does not print, because the method creating the help script just returns it as a String and this returned String is not used.

Comment: I agree very much with the comment on bracing style. I was simply trying to follow the style used by my lecturer in the base code which is provided to us as he prefers this minimal-lines approach. I will certainly stick with the brace on a separate line version in future.

Comment: @AlexM: You may wish to point out to your lecturer - as tactfully as possible - that the industry doesn't follow his style.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to escape the `?` in a char:

```
case '?': showHelp(); break;
```

> is there a more suitable way to implement the 'Exit' option, rather than just having a break after an 'x' is input?

It if fine but it would work the same way if you removed it. What would possibly make more sense would be something like:

```
case 'x': break;
default: showErrorMessage();
```

So if the user enters an unauthorised character, you let him know.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to escape the '?' in a char. Also - you're not doing anything with the String you construct and return from showHelp() currently. You would need to do something with that like:

```
String message;
switch(choice) {
 //.. stuff ommitted
 case '?': message = showHelp(); break;
```

Or you should display the message within showHelp.

Comment: thanks - how about if I were to use:
    case '?': System.out.println(showHelp()); break;